# How do I safely save an object to a database if it insists that certain associations must exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So I have a `Patient` and `Doctor` class, and an `Appointment` join table. I want to be able to create an `Appointment` with just the `Patient` class, without having to associate a `Doctor` id right away.

I'm using postgre-sql.

When I try to do perform the above in rails console, I get the following

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007ff49a6cbdf8 @base=#<Appointment id: 1, date: nil, time_slot: nil, details: nil, doctor_id: nil, patient_id: 1, assigned?: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:date=>["can't be blank"], :time_slot=>["can't be blank"], :doctor=>["must exist"], @details={:date=>[{:error=>:blank}], :time_slot=>[{:error=>:blank}], :doctor=>[{:error=>:blank}]
```

I figure that maybe there is a way to override this, but I am also concerned about data integrity. I don't have any validations in the models, so additionally, I'm not sure why the `Appointment` object not having certain data is an issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can opt out of the default belongs_to presence validation

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doctor, optional: true
end
```